# Is there a way to delete a Firebase project immediately?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am stuck because I hit my project quota due to lots of different pending deletions (I didn't know that they count against the limit).

Is there a way to delete these projects immediately so I can create a new one right away?

Comment: Short answe.... no, it takes minimum 24 hours

Comment: And how can I delete it in 24h?

Comment: That's out of your control. Firebase servers retain your project details for a limited amount of time after you decide to delete it

Answer (score 6):

Short answer.... no, it takes time, After deleting from console, they will send you an email (Project Shutdown Announcement, for confirmation(in case you deleted it by mistake). In case you don't respond to email for un-deletion then they will delete it.

See the attached image, I just deleted a sample project from my firebase console.

> [image]

Comment: Will getting a paid plan give me more projects? I am confused because the paid plan is associated with a single project.

Comment: @FlorianWalther, Sorry I dont have idea about Paid Plan, but since deletion is serious activity, they surely take action after double confirmation. I am sure for that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I requested additional projects and they approved it within 1 day.

Answer (score -1):

- Click project to be deleted in dashboard
- Go to project setting at the left and top of the panel.
- Scroll down to see Delete project.
- Write project name to delete in popup dialog
- Delete !

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can Delete your firebase project from firebase dashboard

> Step 1 Go to your Firebase Console [here](https://console.firebase.google.com)

Now Go to your project, which you want to delete 
[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzOzG.png)

> Step 2 Go to Project Overview

On your Project Dashboard, you will see the App connected to your firebase project, now click on three verticals dots and click on setting, as you can see in the image.

> Step 3 Go to Setting

Now scroll down you will see Delete App and Delete project [Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXSt1.png)

> Step 4 Now click on Delete Project 
>   For Delete Project, it will ask to add project Id Enter Project id and click on delete button.[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Lt2.png)

Enjoy..!!!